# How to replace domain name in $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] to "127.0.0.1"

Tags: php

I am using `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` to get http host information.

How to replace domain name in `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` to "127.0.0.1"

Example

```
http://example.net:22222/folder_nmae
```

to

```
http://127.0.0.1:22222/folder_name
```

Structure of `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` may vary, it may be with or without port or folder name etc.

**Edit**

I have a file get.php in my root directory and want to trigger it periodically using localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: why you need this?

Comment: I have a file get.php in my root directory and want to trigger it periodically using localhost or 127.0.0.1

Comment: so why not you can just put `127.0.0.1` in curl url ?

Comment: Because some hosts are using different ports or folder names

Comment: Just use `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way you can redirect user to `127.0.0.1` if they request `localhost`. Add this `RewriteRule` to `.htaccess` in document root folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/$1 [R,L]
```